# Location of the splash image when using trigger io

Tags: trigger.io, forge

I am trying to figure out the location where I should be adding my custom splash image. I followed the instructions at, http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/launchimage.html#modules-launchimage  however I don't know the folder location to place this image within my trigger project src structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the image anywhere in the `src` folder, the path you give is relative to `src`.

For example, if you have a file `your-app/src/splash.png` then putting `"splash.png"` in `config.json` should work.

If you use the App config page in the Toolkit to select the image it will let you choose from the files in `src` so you don't have to manually enter the path.